# Comunicar dos componentes que no comparten relación entre si en Angular

Tags: angular, rutas, servicio, componentes

Estoy intentando comunicar dos componentes que no tienen relacion alguna entre si, no son hermanos, ni padres, ni hijos uno del otro, además de esto tampoco comparten las rutas, ni las vistas pero tengo que hacer que cuando se produzca un evento en un componente envié una alerta al otro componente. Estoy usando angular 15.
Tengo dos componentes uno tabla-recepcion que esta dentro del componente recepción:

```
<!-- Contenido del componente recepción -->      
    <app-tabla-recepcion ></app-tabla-recepcion>
```

Y otro componente tabla-vendedor que esta dentro del componente vendedor de la siguiente manera:

```
<!-- Contenido del componente vendedor-->
<app-tabla-vendedor></app-tabla-vendedor>
```

tengo la siguiente estructura:

En tabla-recepcion.html tengo un botón que llama a la función notificarTurnoVendedor:

```
     <button
        class="btn btn-danger btn-notificar-vendedor me-md-5"
        (click)="notificarTurnoVendedor()"
      >
        Notificar vendedor
      </button>
```

Dentro de table-recepcion.ts:

```
// devuelve un objeto con la hora en la que ingresaron los vendedores y el nombre de cada uno.
getHoraIngresoVendedor() {
   this.helperService.getHoraIngreso().subscribe((res) => {
     this.getHoraIngreso = res;
   });
 }

// recupera el primer elemento en el objeto con el ingreso de los vendedores, lo almacena en editMessage y se llama a la función changeMesagge que envía esa información a un servicio.
 notificarTurnoVendedor() {
   let array = this.getHoraIngreso;
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {   

     this.editMessage = array[i];
     this.changeMessage();     
     break;
   }
 }

// envia el contenido de editMessage (el primer vendedor de el objeto de vendedores) a un servicio
 changeMessage() {
   this.helperService.changeMessage(this.editMessage);
 }
```

En helperService.ts tengo el siguiente código:

```
  public messageVenta = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  public customMessage = this.messageVenta.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
// recibe lo que trae la variable editMessage y lo guarda en el observable messageVenta que a su vez se guarda en custumMessage

  public changeMessage(msg: string): void {
    this.messageVenta.next(msg);
  }

  private apiUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/horaIngreso/';

// trae la lista de ingreso de vendedores de el backend
  getHoraIngreso() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        return res;
      })
    );
  }
```

El componente que tiene que recibir la información es tabla-vendedor. En tabla-vendedor.ts tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
// trae la informacion desde el observable del servicio
    this.helperService.customMessage.subscribe(
      (msg) => (this.messageVenta = msg)
    );

  }
```

En el tabla-vendedor.html tengo:

```
      <div>
       messageVenta: {{messageVenta}}
      </div>
```

Con esto no consigo que la vista del componente tabla-vendedor se actualice cuando se envia la información desde tabla-recepcion.

En el app-routing tengo:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   
  { path: 'login', component: InicioComponent },
  { path: 'recepcion', component: RecepcionComponent},
  { path: 'venta', component: VendedorComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
 
];
```

La verdad es que he probado de todo, mediante input, output, eventEmitter, servicios, etc. Ya no se mas que probar. Alguna idea de como puedo resolver este problema.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que los componentes estén usando la misma instancia del servicio?

Comment: Si si, usan la misma instancia.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que compartas el código completo en StackBlitz para poder reproducirlo

Comment: Perfecto, hay lo comparto en stackBlitz. Preferis que suba el código del proyecto completo o solo la parte del código que estoy intentando comunicar?? para mi es lo mismo, como creas que va a ser mas útil.

Comment: Lo mínimo necesario para poder reproducir el problema.

Comment: Perfecto, te paso el link. La ruta por defecto es '/venta' lamentablemente para poder ver lo que contiene recepción hay que modificar la ruta manualmente por '/recepcion' porque saque todo lo vinculado con el login que es quien lo gestiona el direccionamiento a las rutas. Cualquier otra cosa que necesites avísame. LINK: [enlace](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c2edsz?file=src/app/componentes/tabla-vendedor/tabla-vendedor.component.ts)